# ElasticSearch - Find documents that are closely related to query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch to search a product database. I need the search to find documents that have fields where the field data might be close to the search term but not exact. For example, if the user searches for the model number "T9200" then I would like the document with the model number "T 9200" to be returned or visa-versa. From what I can tell I need some sort of filter for concatenation but I haven't been able to find what I believe will work. Can anyone provide any references or information? All of my code is written is written in Ruby but the json interpretation should be the same as the ElasticSearch documentation.

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 },
    analysis: {
      filter: {
        synonym: {
          type: "synonym",
          ignore_case: true,
          synonyms: File.readlines(Rails.root / 'config' / 'analysis' / 'data' / 'synonyms.txt').map(&:chomp)
        }
    },
  analyzer: {
    synonym: {
      tokenizer: "whitespace",
      filter: ["synonym", "lowercase", "stop", "snowball"]
    }
  }
} do
  mappings dynamic: 'false' do
    indexes :name, analyzer: 'synonym'
    indexes :status, analyzer: 'english'
    #indexes :description, analyzer: 'english'
    indexes :part_number, analyzer: 'english'
    indexes :text, analyzer: 'english'
    indexes :normal_model, type: 'nested' do
      indexes :name, analyzer: 'synonym'
      indexes :number, analyzer: 'english'
      indexes :machine_type, analyzer: 'english'

      indexes :normal_brand, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :name, analyzer: 'synonym'
      end
    end
  end
end




 def as_indexed_json(options={})
    as_json(
        only: [:name, :description, :part_number, :url_key, :image, :price, :shipping, :warranty, :eta, :status, :sku],
        include: {
            normal_model: { only: [:name, :number, :machine_type],
                include: {
                    normal_brand: { only: :name}
                }
            }
        }
    )
 end



@products = Product.search(
           query: { 
             query_string: {
              #query: "*manual* AND status:\"Disabled\""
                #fields: ['name', 'normal_model.normal_brand.name', 'normal_model.name', '_all'],

             query: "#{params[:q]} AND status:\"Viewable On Website & Backend\""
                #query:  "*" + params[:q]+ "*"
             }
          }
          ).page(page).per(15)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more examples about what you consider "close"? Do you just want to ignore spaces? Is "S9200" close? How about "T9300"? "T9201"? "T92000"?

Comment: All of the examples you just provided would eventually be considered close for the implementation that I need. I do believe that just ignoring spaces should fix most of my issues though.

Comment: For the model field, I don't think you want to use a whitespace analyzer because that will split "T 9200" into 2 separate terms. I don't know of a filter that will remove spaces but you may not need that if you use fuzzy queries for search.

Comment: Do I have to use a match query to utilize the fuzzy query you are talking about or can I use the query string like I am already doing?

Comment: You should be able to use query string. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html